# macOS kernel panics when many external drives are connected

Tags: macos, hard-drive, ssd, kernel-panic

I recently purchased a 5-bay HDD enclosure that I filled with hard drives. I connected this along with around 4-5 SSDs with NVMe adapters to my Mac mini via a powered USB hub.

I noticed that when transferring files between the drives, or even when just using macOS itself without interacting with the drives, there is a high likelihood of kernel panics increases to a few per day, depending on what I'm doing. File transfer for a prolonged period almost always results in a kernel panic. Kernel panics also occur outside of file transfers, although they usually take longer to happen in this case.

When the Mac kernel panics, the external monitor usually flashes pink for a split second before blacking out, and then the Mac reboots. Upon login I am always greeted with a "Problem Report" that I can send to Apple.

Why are these kernel panics happening, and what can I do to stop them? I am running macOS Sonoma on my Mac mini.